# Iterating over Index in Python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, indexing, iteration

I am trying to write a for loop to iterate through my index and only keep the ones that have duplicates.

My current dataframe is two merged together

```
                  0.0102700     0.0308099     0.0616199      0.123240  \   
5000000000010  4.330760e-05  4.442720e-05  9.232970e-05  1.994190e-04   
5000000000238  6.006910e-04  6.041130e-04  1.220220e-03  2.500240e-03
...
```

.

```
              0.00902317     0.0270695     0.0451159     0.0631622  \ 
5000000000010  6.962980e-05  7.063750e-05  7.165970e-05  7.269680e-05   
5000000000234  4.638970e-04  4.716010e-04  4.794320e-04  4.873930e-04
```

.

```
 New = pd.concat([SFR_low, SFR_high])
 New = New.sort_index()
 print(New)

                 0.00902317     0.0102700     0.0270695     0.0308099  \
5000000000010  6.962980e-05           NaN  7.063750e-05           NaN   
5000000000010           NaN  4.330760e-05           NaN  4.442720e-05   
5000000000081  6.299210e-05           NaN  6.299320e-05           NaN   
5000000000082           NaN  8.176550e-04           NaN  8.172630e-04
```

I need to a new dataframe that only keeps the rows with duplicate indices.

Comment: please edit the question and add your code and your DataFrame (or a part of it)

Comment: Just did so now, but I don't have any code yet, as these files have just been read in.

Comment: You want to keep the values, the row or the column? And duplicated where? In the same row, column, or whole table? And please try something, and if you fail then rework the question. This might help you out for the code needed to eliminate duplicates http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_count_values.html theres some code to check frecuency on DataFrames. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False`:

```
print (df.index[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)])
Int64Index([1000, 1000, 1002, 1002], dtype='int64')


for i in df.index[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]:
    print (i)
1000
1000
1002
1002
```

If need filter rows with duplicated index, use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (New.index.duplicated(keep=False))
[ True  True False False]

print (New[New.index.duplicated(keep=False)])
               0.00902317  0.0102700  0.0270695  0.0308099  0.0451159  \
5000000000010         NaN   0.000043        NaN   0.000044        NaN   
5000000000010     0.00007        NaN   0.000071        NaN   0.000072   

               0.0616199  0.0631622  0.123240  
5000000000010   0.000092        NaN  0.000199  
5000000000010        NaN   0.000073       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [1000,1000,1001,1002,1002]
for i in li:
    temp = i
    count = 0
    for j in li:
        if j is temp:
            count +=1
    if count > 1:
        print i
```

This solves your requirement?

Comment: The OP is using `pandas` not a list, this answer is not relevant to the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

try some code first before asking:
there are lot of duplicate questions

```
a = [1000,1000,1001,1002,1002]
c = [x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1]
print c
```